# Is there a way of kicking everyone with a certain role in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm trying to make a command that kicks all the members with a certain role. It's not going very well - this is my current code:

```
import discord 
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import has_permissions

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "k!")

@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kickall(ctx):
    role_id = 754061046704242799
    for role_id in roles: #roles undefined lol
        try:
            await member.kick()
        except:
            continue
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can iterate through all members, and check if they have the specified role. If they do, you can kick them.

```
@client.command(pass_context=True)
@has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def kick(ctx, role: discord.Role, reason: str=None):
    for member in ctx.guild.members:
        if role in member.roles: # does member have the specified role?
            await ctx.guild.kick(member, reason=reason)
```

The usage would be `k! kick <role> <reason(optional)>`

I'd recommend looking at the [documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role) for more details.

The parameters (`ctx, role: discord.Role, reason: str=None`) are as follows:

- `ctx` - is passed in by default. This contains all the context information such as message author, server the message was sent in etc
- `role: discord.Role` - the user must specify a role to kick when calling the command. The colon tells python and discord.py the type to try and convert the parameter to, meaning that it will convert a role name (i.e. a string) into a `discord.Role` object, so you can do operations on it such as comparing roles.
- `reason: str=None` - an optional parameter (default is `None`). If this is provided, the users kicked will see this string as the reason message for being kicked.

Comment: Could you include a little more context, for example a MWE?